# Where is the documentation for Twilio's SendGrid c# Library?

Tags: documentation, sendgrid

I downloaded the SendGrid NuGet package but can't find the documentation for it anywhere online...

To be specific I'm looking for something that shows me classes, methods, and properties.
Something similar to: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm#!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I can't find a set of docs of classes/methods/properties, but there is this [document on usage covering all the APIs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USAGE.md) and then the [API reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/authentication) has all the detail you need on what API requests and responses should look like.